# JSTL set a variable to the length of a string

Tags: java, xml, jstl

I have some code that I'm trying to use to get the length of an xml node value in jstl.

```
<x:forEach select="$person/tel"  var="phone">
        <x:if select="$phone/@type='office'">
            <c:set var="length" value=${fn:length("${phone}")}/>                            
            <c:out value="${length}"/>
        </x:if>
</x:forEach>
```

I'm getting an error where the function is called.

"org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /edit.jsp (line: 87, column: 35) quote symbol expected"

I need to get the length because the length determines how I parse it and write it to the page.

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this or if I'm even approaching this correctly.

Updated code:

```
<x:forEach select="$person/tel"  var="tel">
                        <x:if select="$tel/@type='office'">
                            <x:set var="number" select="$tel/phone"/>
                            <c:set var="length" value="${fn:length(number)}"/>                  
                            <c:out value="${length}"/>
                        </x:if>
</x:forEach>
```

Comment: Why did you use the tag javascript? I think you meant Java.

Comment: Well, you didn't quote the value of the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't use `"${phone}"` inside `fn:length()`.

The correct way should be:

```
 <c:set var="length" value=${fn:length(phone)}/>
```

Comment: Is passing that xml variable to the length function a valid thing to do? I've updated my question with my new code. Now, the output that's printed out is just a length of 1. I know the node exists and all the "if" statements are valid.

Comment: `<x:set var="number" select="$tel/phone"/>` check if it's a string and is being set correctly (not empty).

Comment: I can print the "number" to the screen with <x:out select="$number"/>
But not with <c:out> That leads me to think that these two don't mix very well.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. The problem is that:

```
<x:set var="number" select="$tel/phone"/>
```

does not set a string, but is simply a representation of an xml node. To convert the node contents to string, I did:

```
<c:set var="phonenumber">
    <x:out select="$number"/>
</c:set>
```

x:out converts the node contents to a string, and wrapping it in c:set sets the variable.